# Why are a form's system buttons highlighted when calling WindowFromPoint in MouseMove event?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2

Calling WindowFromPoint within the MouseMove event of a TWinControl causes a MouseOver event at the point passed to WindowFromPoint. Is this a VCL bug? Anybody know if there is a workaround?

[image]

Here's the demo code:

```
unit Unit7;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm7 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form7: TForm7;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm7.Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  WindowFromPoint(Point(Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y - 40));
end;

end.
```

DFM:

```
object Form7: TForm7
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form7'
  ClientHeight = 40
  ClientWidth = 116
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 24
    Top = 7
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnMouseMove = Button1MouseMove
  end
end
```

I'm using Delphi XE2 on Windows 7 Pro 64bit. I can also reproduce using Delphi 7.

Comment: WindowFromPoint is Windows API. So doesn't seem to be a VCL issue.

Comment: @TLama - Actually, the form can be any size, but the cursor must be 40 pixels or less directly below the system buttons.

Comment: Perhaps this article from Raymond Chen is relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/18/10131176.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this with a simplest C++ application and observed the same behavior, this is not a VCL bug (as David mentioned in the comments). It's not related with mouse movements BTW, anytime you call `WindowFromPoint` passing a caption button's coordinates, the peculiarity occurs. And it occurs only on the windows that belong to the thread that makes the call to the function.

So, for a workaround, you can call `WindowFromPoint` from a thread. Simple example below, not really a background thread as the code waits for it to finish:

```
type
  TGetWndThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FPoint: TPoint;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; Point: TPoint);
  end;

constructor TGetWndThread.Create(AOwner: TComponent; Point: TPoint);
begin
  FPoint := Point;
  inherited Create;
end;

procedure TGetWndThread.Execute;
begin
  ReturnValue := WindowFromPoint(FPoint);
end;

..

var
  Wnd: HWND;
  Thr: TGetWndThread;
begin
  Thr := TGetWndThread.Create(nil, Point(Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y - 40));
  Wnd := Thr.WaitFor;
  Thr.Free;
  .. // use Wnd
```

It would make sense to test for the conditions which the bug is displayed (OS, themes..) and make the code conditional to avoid the overhead where unnecessary.

Comment: Hi Sertac. That works, thanks very much. Do you have any idea how to turn off the highlighting completely? The reason I ask is that in TChromeTabs I handle my own tab dragging/dropping. When dragging a tab, the system buttons are still highlighted when the cursor is over them. Chrome does exhibit this behaviour so I guess there must be a way of temporarily disabling the highlight effect. Perhaps this should be a new question?

Comment: @norge - You're welcome.   I can't think of anything right now, the first thing I'd test is to try handling WM_NCHITTEST but there might be some difference handling it for DWM.